# MySQL query with group contact

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, mysql-select-db

Let's say I have a table called "test" with the following design:

```
SELECT type, name, `key` FROM test
```

```
type | name    | key
------------------------
  0  | maria   | 123
  1  | gabriel | 455
  0  | rihanna | 69
  1  | chris   | 7
  1  | martin  | 112
```

The next query allows me to get all data in one line:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY type) types, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY type) names, GROUP_CONCAT(`key` ORDER BY type) `keys` FROM test
```

```
  types   |               names                |      keys
------------------------------------------------------------------
0,0,1,1,1 | rihanna,maria,martin,chris,gabriel | 69,123,112,7,455
```

But that's not exactly what I need. It'd be perfect if I was able to create a query that returns the following result:

```
types_0 |     names_0    |  keys_0  | types_1 |         names_1         |    keys_1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0, 0  | maria, rihanna |  123, 69 |   1, 1  | gabriel, chris, martin  | 455, 7, 112
```

Is there any way to create such query? or wouldn't it even make sense at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is kind of possible but I wouldn't do it. It would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY type) types, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY type) names, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`key` ORDER BY type) `keys` 
  FROM test
  WHERE type = 0
) AS _type0,
(
  SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY type) types, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY type) names, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`key` ORDER BY type) `keys` 
  FROM test
  WHERE type = 1
) AS _type1;
```

There is no way to generate more columns dynamically if it finds more types. This is typical of *pivot table* queries -- you must know the distinct values before you write the query.

I would instead do this:

```
SELECT 
  type,
  GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) names, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`key` ORDER BY name) `keys` 
FROM test
GROUP BY type;
```

And the output should look like:

```
 type |         names        |  keys
------------------------------------------------------------------
 0    | maria,rihanna        | 123,69
 1    | chris,gabriel,martin | 7,455,112
```

*edit:* I made this query order by `name` within each group, per suggestion from @GarethD's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN type END ORDER BY Type) AS types_0,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN name END ORDER BY Type) AS names_0,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN `key` END ORDER BY Type) AS keys_0,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN type END ORDER BY Type) AS types_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN name END ORDER BY Type) AS names_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN `key` END ORDER BY Type) AS keys_1
FROM   Test;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d700e/4)**

Or if you don't know the number of types you can generate the SQL dynamically and use a prepared statement:

```
SET @SQL = '';

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CONCAT('GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = ', type, ' THEN type END ORDER BY Type) AS types_', type, ','
                            'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = ', type, ' THEN name END ORDER BY Type) AS names_', type, ','
                            'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type = ', type, ' THEN `key` END ORDER BY Type) AS keys_', type
                    )), ' FROM Test;')
INTO    @SQL
FROM    Test;

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d700e/9)**

**HOWEVER**, just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should, and I agree with Bill Karwin, the most sensible way to display this data would be to group by type. In addition your query is not determinisitic, you should order by something more than just type, to ensure the order of the names and keys are consistent.

Comment: +1 yes, I agree one should sort by something other than `type` which is by definition at a tie within each group by type. I'll edit my answer to show that.